# Additional persistent disks are not created when using --source-machine-image with 'gcloud beta compute instances create' CLI command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The following works great - creating VM from source image *and* additional persistent disk(s).

```
gcloud compute instances create ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
--image-project ${PROJECT_NAME} \
--image ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME} \
--zone=${ZONE_NAME} \
--create-disk=size=128GB,type=pd-balanced,name=${INSTANCE_NAME}-home,device-name=homedisk
```

The following, however, creates a VM BUT no additional disk(s) are created.

```
gcloud beta compute instances create ${INSTANCE_NAME} \
    --source-machine-image ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME} \
    --zone=${ZONE_NAME} \
    --create-disk=size=128GB,type=pd-balanced,name=${INSTANCE_NAME}-homedisk,device-name=homedisk
```

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/create) for the command does not suggest that `--source-machine-image` and `--create-disk` cannot work in tandem. The property overrides when creating a VM from machine image suggests that any of the properties can be overridden.

Any insights as to what might be going on?

Comment: Hi, it's normal that on the `gcloud command` you have `name=${INSTANCE_NAME}-home` and `name=${INSTANCE_NAME}-homedisk` for the `gcloud beta`?

Comment: @Pierre-Alexandre I am not sure what you mean but if I understand correctly, yes it is normal. The name key in --create-disk is a user settable parameter that can be called anything. I just happened to call it -home on first and -homedisk on the other.

Answer (score 0):

the problem here is with the `--source-machine-image ${BASE_IMAGE_NAME}` flag because your BASE_IMAGE_NAME must already have the desired additional disk, that is why it is not being created, because it is creating everything from the `BASE_IMAGE_NAME` which does not have an additional disk, try it by creating a new `Machine image` with the desired additional disk attached and then run your `gcloud beta compute instances create` again (the second command you have) and confirm that it creates the instance based on that `Machine image` including the additional disk.

If you need to create a new instance with 1 additional disk you should use (your first command) `--image ${NAME} --image-project ${PROJECT}`

So `--source-machine-image` and `--image ... --image-project` are very different.

Here is the documentation for `Machine images` which may explain this better.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-images

Comment: This seems correct but doesn't consistently explain the property override behavior/provision. My understanding from the documentation was that the "property override" should allow me to take a base machine image (really a template plus disk image) and while spawing a copy, change a few configs (including the num. of disks). For instance, why allow change to RAM or CPU type? The same argument that if I wanted 4 CPUs, I should've created in the original machine. I think i am missing machine image's fundamental use case/tenets.